# Joins returning Null values?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Could anyone explain why I'm getting Null values for all but the first four records that my code returns?
My Teachers table has only 4 records so I imagine my join syntax is incorrect.
Sorry, I havn't fully gotten my head around joins yet.

```
USE Assignment
GO
CREATE VIEW PupilsAges AS
SELECT Pupil_ID,PupilDetails.FName,
PupilDetails.LName, PupilDetails.DOB,
DATEDIFF(year, GETDATE(),PupilDetails.DOB) AS "PupilAge",
Instrument,
(Teachers.FName+' '+Teachers.LName) AS Teacher
FROM Teachers JOIN  PupilDetails
ON  Teachers.ID = PupilDetails.Pupil_ID
```

Comment: As per tje join condition of query it looks like pupil can be a teacher too and vice versa. Is that correct? If not then it think you need to join on teachers.id and pupildetails.teacherid.

Comment: Please next time include the DDL statments for table structures so that we can assist with more solid responses. Also before complicating things with creating a view, test and debug just the SELECT component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your joining `Teachers.ID = PupilDetails.Pupil_ID`

This looks to be the problem, you have not listed the schema for the tables, however try something similar to this:

```
USE Assignment
GO
CREATE VIEW PupilsAges AS
SELECT Pupil_ID,PupilDetails.FName,
PupilDetails.LName, PupilDetails.DOB,
DATEDIFF(year, GETDATE(),PupilDetails.DOB) AS "PupilAge",
Instrument,
(Teachers.FName+' '+Teachers.LName) AS Teacher
FROM Teachers JOIN  PupilDetails
ON  Teachers.ID = PupilDetails.Teacher_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to join to a field that relates data between the two tables. In tea hers the id field should identify a teacher. In pupilDetails pupil_id identifies a pupil. You want to join on a teacher_id field, if one exists.

With your current query you only have 4 teachers so once you pass the first 4 students it doesn't know who to join students 5+ to. When you join on the proper field the teachers should repeat.